# get common id numbers from sqldatabase table c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013

I need to know how to get all the clientID that are #2 so i could get the programs they are assigned to...so far my code only gets the first clientID with #2 in it...

```
int progs;
string Command = @"select * from clientprogram where clientProgClientID = @clientID;";
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(mycon))
{
     mConnection.Open();
     using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
     {
          cmd2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@clientID", lblcID.Text));
          using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
          {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                     progs = (int)reader["clientProgramID"];
                     cmbProgram.Items.Add(progs);
                }
          }
     }
     mConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: should `if (reader.Read())` be a loop ?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if (reader.Read())
```

to

```
while (reader.Read())
```

It seems it should be in a loop to add records recursively rather than just the first one

Answer (score 1):

of course it only get the first result because you are reading it only once.
use `while(reader.Read())` instead of `if(reader.Read())`.

```
while(reader.Read())
{
      progs = (int)reader["clientProgramID"];
      cmbProgram.Items.Add(progs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if (reader.Read())
```

to

```
while(reader.Read())
```

side note; don't use `select *` when you only need single column data, use `select Coumnname from yourtable`

Answer (score 0):

```
int progs;
string Command = @"select * from clientprogram where clientProgClientID =     @clientID;";
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(mycon))
{
 mConnection.Open();
 using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
  {
      cmd2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@clientID", lblcID.Text));
      using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
      {
            while (reader.Read()) // CHANGE TO THIS
            {
                 progs = (int)reader["clientProgramID"];
                 cmbProgram.Items.Add(progs);
            }
      }
 }
 mConnection.Close();
```

}